# Stream and control a playlist to RTMP

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to stream a playlist of files from ffmpeg to an RTMP server.
I've managed to get a single file to be streamed correctly, and (I think) a playlist by using:

```
"concat:file1.pm4|file2.mp4|file3.mp4"
```

I then tried to use the concatenation method from a txt file they explain here:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

And was able to get it to work. However I seem to have some problems with controlling it. For example, I have no idea if it is possible to tell ffmpeg to skip this file and play the next one in the list, or to pause the stream at all. I already tested editing the txt file while it is streaming, but that didn't seem to affect what was already streaming at all.

Any idea how I can control my stream from the console? My end goal would be to make the control into a full web interface later, but I'm not even sure if ffmpeg is my best option to do this.

Any help with ffmpeg or any other options to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't use `concat:` with `mp4`, as mentioned on the page you linked. `ffmpeg` supports some interactive commands (eg. for filters) but for playlist control you'll have to implement your own solution using ffmpeg's libs.

Comment: Can you point me to the best library to do that? Can't find much on google